# Finding maximum value in a Hashmap of Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

So I'm still relatively new to Java and this question may be fairly trivial but I'm having issues getting an answer.

I'm trying to find the max value within a hashmap I created. I initialized the hashmap and filled it but here's the structure:

```
HashMap<Double,HashMap<Double,Double>>
```

any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

EDIT: For clarification I would like to know the value of largest entry in the hashtable

Comment: maximum key or value? the answer depends on which one you want...

Comment: Do you mean: considering all the first-level keys, second-level keys and values as a single set of `double` values, find the maximum value? Or, is it something else?

Comment: Please show any code you have so far, along with any problems you've encountered -- wrong output, compiler messages, and exception stack traces.

Comment: Be clear about what you mean, please...

Comment: I feel obligated to add that, often when you have nested maps, is a sign that you should have another class. Then also these things can be easily achieved with static fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a root map full of nested maps.
You will iterate on all values in the root map - fetching nested maps. And then iterate on each value on each nested map.

Compexity will be O(n) where n - number of all keys in the all nested maps plus number of keys in root map.

I think you can not find the max value faster if you use the HashMaps.

The code will look like:

```
final HashMap<Double, HashMap<Double, Double>> data = new HashMap<Double, HashMap<Double, Double>>();

Double prev = null;
for (final HashMap<Double, Double> nestedMap : data.values()) {
    for (final Double value : nestedMap.values()) {
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = value;
            continue;
        }
        prev = Math.max(value, prev);
    }
}

System.out.println("The max value is " + prev);
```